# WSAEventSelect, one event, multiple sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I am rewriting code in my software to support multiple connections, until now, I use select. To get my software more portable I changed to WSAPoll. After finding a bug in WSAPoll which Microsoft will not solve, I want to change to the suggested WSAEventSelect. As WSAWaitForMultipleEvents only support up to 64 Events and for resource saving reasons, I want to connect a hEvent to multiple sockets. My question now is, is

```
rc = WSAEventSelect(s1, hEventObject1, FD_READ);
rc = WSAEventSelect(s2, hEventObject1, FD_READ);
```

a legit operation? Please answer only if you have hard facts, not opinions. Or you have used that way yourself before. Also, I do not want to use boost for some reasons (for e.g. 1.52 has a bug in the socket part (funny that is nearly the same bug as WSAPoll)). Also please no "Why don't you..."

Comment: Hard fact: If you set up a one-to-many mapping you lose the ability to uniquely identify an object. I wonder what you hope to achieve with the code snippet posted in your question.

Comment: @IInspectable of course you are right. I got to iterate through all the sockets with WSAEnumNetworkEvents even if they do not signal anything. I just try to keep things in a single thread as the rest of the code I refactor is not threadsafe at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

A single wait event should not be associated with multiple sockets.  Each socket should use it own individual event.  Otherwise, if multiple sockets were to use the same event, you would not know which socket satisfied the wait when that event is signaled.  Even if you could, there would also be a race condition when `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` is called to get the event data, as it resets the event, which might have already been set by another socket.  So you could lose events.

To get around the 64-handle limit, do what the `WaitForMultipleObjects()` documentation says to do:

> To wait on more than MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, use one of the following methods:
>
> • Create a thread to wait on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS handles, then wait on that thread plus the other handles. Use this technique to break the handles into groups of MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS.
>
> • Call RegisterWaitForSingleObject to wait on each handle. A wait thread from the thread pool waits on MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS registered objects and assigns a worker thread after the object is signaled or the time-out interval expires.

Otherwise, use `WSAAsyncSelect()` instead, and let it notify you via a window message whenever any given socket satisfies the requested conditions.

Comment: I'd suggest an alternative, namely using IO completion ports. They're a bit of a pain, but allow you to wait on a single object without losing the ability to discern between the sockets.

Comment: I am aware of that. It is about a kind of hack, keeping things single threaded as a part of the code I have to use is not threadsafe (yet). I take the loss and would iterate through the sockets with WSAEventSelect. This is easier than building a kind of queue system which leads to the same effect at the end. Like this, it is a special way to tread that, I know. Unfortunately that way is not described in the microsoft help.

Comment: @Hasturkun Yeah, but I did not found a easy tutorial with multiple sockets. The things I read about IO completion ports look very complex. With linux/Mac OS it is really easy with poll(). I did not want to learn the next microsoft own way to do things so I tried to stay close to the things I already now, the WSA stuff.

Comment: @MartinSchlott: I/O Completion Ports are not new, they have been around for a long time, and were added to WinSock when 2.0 was first released.  See MSDN for details: [Windows Sockets 2.0: Write Scalable Winsock Apps Using Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx). You can associate multiple sockets with a single IOCP, and whenever it is signaled, you can use user-defined context information to know which socket was triggered each time.

Comment: @MartinSchlott: And you don't need to (but should) use worker threads with IOCPs, you can poll IOCP status info using `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` in the same thread that is managing the sockets.

Comment: Remy, your first and third sentences contract each other.  Is it impossible, as your first sentence claims... or possible but not helpful, as your third sentence claims.