# Can WSAEventSelect() be used in multiple threads to increase sockets limit?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi

This [article](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/advanced.html) says the following:

> The Windows event mechanism (e.g. WaitForMultipleObjects()) can only
>   wait on 64 event objects at a time. Winsock 2 provides the
>   WSAEventSelect() function which lets you use Windows’ event mechanism
>   to wait for events on sockets. Because it uses Windows’ event
>   mechanism, you can only wait for events on 64 sockets at a time. If
>   you want to wait on more than 64 Winsock event objects at a time, you
>   need to use multiple threads, each waiting on no more than 64 of the
>   sockets.

Is this statement correct? I want to monitor 300 sockets to see if they have pending data to be read, so can I just create 5 threads and use `WSAEventSelect()` to do that?

Comment: **[Please try doing background research before posting here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936131/wsaeventselect-one-event-multiple-sockets)**

Comment: [Windows Sockets 2.0: Write Scalable Winsock Apps Using Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx)

Comment: @IInspectable So the answer to my question is No, or you mean that IOCP are a better approach to take?

Comment: @joseph_m See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19936666/2422013) on the question I linked earlier, it explains how to bypass the 64 socket limit.

Comment: A single call to [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) is limited to `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` objects. Scalable network applications are generally written using [I/O Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - yes, the statement you quoted is correct.  The various `WaitFor` functions can only wait on a maximum of 64 objects at one time.  So, to wait on 300 socket events simultaneously, you would have to wait on 5 threads, where 4 threads are waiting on 64 events each, and the 5th thread is waiting on 44 events.

If you want to write *scalable* socket code, you should not be using waitable socket events at all.  Use an I/O Completion Port instead.  You can associate multiple sockets with a single IOCP handle, and have multiple threads (preferably one per CPU core) waiting for notifications from that single IOCP.  Use IOCP-enabled socket functions (`WSAConnect()`, `WSAAcept()`, `WSARead()`, `WSASend()`, etc) and let them notify you when their work is done.  This allows you to process multiple sockets in parallel with minimal overhead.

Refer to this article for more details:

[Windows Sockets 2.0: Write Scalable Winsock Apps Using Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302334.aspx)

Comment: That same article also talks about `select()` being the same as `WSAEventSelect()` (.i.e. Can be used in multiple threads to increase sockets limit). Is this statement about `select()` also correct?

Comment: `select()` has different limitations on different platforms, but on Windows, `select()` is limited to 64 sockets at a time by default. See the `FD_SETSIZE` define in `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h`.  You can manually redefine `FD_SETSIZE` to some other value prior to `#include <winsock.h>`, though.  But I would not recommend using a single `select()` call for a large number of sockets.  If you get that high, you likely need a code rewrite anyway.